# image not showing in browser using easy thumbnail with Amazon S3 in Django Project

Tags: django, django-templates, easy-thumbnails

I am working on Django project and using easy thumbnails for cropping the images. Previously I used the in local enviornment and its working fine. but when I move media to Amazon S3 then the images not showing ( could not load the image) in the browser.

easy-thumbnail library [link](https://pypi.org/project/easy-thumbnails/)

image tag in the template:-

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="{% thumbnail destination.destination_image 1200x800 quality=95 crop %}" alt="">
```

image tag in browser:-

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/media/destination/myimage.jpg.1200x800_q95_crop.jpg" alt="">
```

But when I remove the **(.1200x800_q95_crop.jpg)** this part through web developer tools in img tag. then it's working. but the image size and crop options are not working.

I want to crop and resize images when it's showing in the browser.